# Run FileZilla on Debian

Tags: debian, package-management, filezilla

I'm new on Debian GNU/Linux, and I installed FileZilla but I don't know how to run it. When I execute this command:

```
dpkg -l | grep -i "filezilla"
```

I get:

```
ii  filezilla-common                     3.7.3-1                            all          Architecture independent files for filezilla
```

So I guess it installed.

Comment: Please ask on superuser, SO is for programming only!

Comment: No problem, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: btw, `sudo apt-get install filezilla` then just run `filezilla`. This will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't got it installed. Execute `sudo apt-get install filezilla`, then run it by executing `filezilla`. `filezilla-common` is not FileZilla itself (but files from FileZilla needed by other applications)